# Invalid Chai property: called. Did you mean "all"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my node.js code using Mocha, Sinon, and chai.

```
var callback = function (err, resultSet) {
    should.exist(resultSet);
    stubbedExecuteSqlQuery.should.be.called;
    done();
};
stubbedExecuteSqlQuery.yields(null, expectedResultSet);
db.getResults(param1,param2, user, callback);
```

when the above code gets executed, it throws an error :

```
Invalid Chai property: called. Did you mean "all"?
```

The code used to work fine on chai version `^3.5.0` but after my recent package upgrade to `^4.1.2` the code has stopped working and has started throwing such errors.

I tried searching for it on the internet but could not find any useful information.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to Chai's current documentation, the syntax should be the following :  `spy.should.have.been.called()`. Also you should take a look at the breaking changes of the different versions that you've skipped : http://www.chaijs.com/releases/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Chai property when calling calledOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314317/invalid-chai-property-when-calling-calledonce)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I think it had something to do with using **.yields**
I ended up using **.calledOnce** . Try the following:

```
assert(stubbedExecuteSqlQuery.calledOnce);
```

The upside with this is that if needed you can do **.calledTwice** etc..